# Node AWS S3 getObject firing httpDone before file stream completes

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, unzip, aws-sdk

I'm using the AWS s3 getObject method in a node application to download a zip file, and then using child_process.exec to call unzip on it:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(file_path);
s3.getObject(params).
on('httpData', function(chunk) { 
    process.stdout.write("."); 
    file.write(chunk); 
}).
on('httpDone', function() { 
    file.end(); 
    console.log('Download Complete'); 
    self.emit('downloadComplete');
}).
send();
```

and on the `downloadComplete` event, this code is called, which throws the error:

```
exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('unzip -o -qq ' + src + ' -d ' + dest, function (error, stdout, stderr) { 
    callback(stderr);
});
```

The exec call comes back with this error:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

However, if I set a short timeout before I try the unzip, i.e:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    self.emit('downloadComplete');
}, 100);
```

It works. Is there a bug in the AWS node lib, or maybe am I using the wrong completion event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should instead emit your download complete event in a `finish` event handler on the file stream:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(file_path);
file.on('finish', function() {
  self.emit('downloadComplete');
});
s3.getObject(params).
  on('httpData', function(chunk) { 
    process.stdout.write("."); 
    file.write(chunk); 
  }).
  on('httpDone', function() { 
    file.end(); 
    console.log('Download Complete'); 
  }).
  send();
```

On an unrelated note, you should probably also use normal streams so that backpressure can do its thing when the disk can't keep up. For example:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(file_path);
s3.getObject(params)
  .createReadStream()
  .pipe(file)
  .on('finish', function() {
    self.emit('downloadComplete');
  });
```

Comment: Ridiculously fast answer, fixed the issue and improved my code. Many thanks. Non-critical: the httpData event no longer seems to get fired in your second code snippet -- is there another way I can provide feedback during large downloads? Cheers

Comment: The `httpData` doesn't fire because it's a normal stream instead (`createReadStream()`). You could listen on the `data` and `end` events on the stream piped to `file` to know when data gets passed through.

Comment: been searching for ever for a solution like this. thanks